# Upload multiple documents to same library item

Tags: 2013, document-library, jquery, client

Is it possible to upload multiple documents to the same item in SharePoint 2013 using jquery ?

I'm trying to add multiple documents to single record in a document library

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 5):

You can create Document Set in document library.

you can add multiple documents in document set and each document set will act as single item for document library.

Answer (score 2):

- As far as I know this is not possible, to add the multiple documents to the document library item.
- You can add the multiple attachments to the **list** not the **document library**.
- One document have the items properties in the **Document Library** and one item can have multiple attachments/documents in the **list**.
- For your [reference](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/146232/upload-multiple-attachments-in-a-sharepoint-list)
- Hope this will hepl you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use List to attach multiple documents to same item, but adding multiple documents to same item in document library won't work.

List Item and Multiple Attachments is the key for you.

Answer (score -1):

In document library we can create File/document not Item. 
In List we can create Item

Like you said you have to attached multiple documents for item in document library. so it is possible. each document in document library have multiple properties.

Attachment is related to SharePoint list Item. so you can add multiple attachments to SharePoint list Item